# Navigating website with Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullscreen

On my website [www.pburtchaell.com](http://pburtchaell.com), I want to implement full-screen sections with navigation between the sections.

Currently I have each section of my site (about, services, work, connect) divided into four full-screen sections with an ID tag for each, for example:

```
<section id="services">
<!-- Section Content -->
</section>

<section id="works">
<!-- Section Content -->
</section>
```

Using jQuery's $.scrollTo() function, I will enable "next" and "previous" navigation between each section. I will also hide all overflow so you would not be able to navigate the site with anything else than these "next" and "previous" buttons.

However, the problems lies here: within some sections -especially on mobile devices- the content often extends out the user's viewport. For example, the services section requires scrolling to view all the content unless the viewport is 1920px, which is to be expected.

Is there anyway to allow navigation **TO AND FROM** the sections using **ONLY** the button navigation (or perhaps arrow key navigation), but to allow scrolling within the section itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use some ideas from Parallax scrolling, for this you can use one of jquery plugins for this: [http://inspirationfeed.com/resources/tools/5-best-jquery-plugins-for-parallax-scrolling/](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

so you'll have more clear way of managing your sections, also you can use

```
github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys
```

to create good key map structure.